How to analize error and stacktrace in unmanaged code in net core docker container
I have floating bug that sometimes abort my net core 6 service in docker container.
Last logs that I see:
[2024-07-26 08:23:57.467 +00:00 INF] ...my logs
dotnet: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

or
[2024-07-26 08:23:57.467 +00:00 INF] ...my logs
dotnet: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Killed

I use some own unmanaged code and third party graphics c libs in my service. And I guess that the cause of fail in it.
But how I could root cause or stacktrace more precise?
